# WPF Observabledictionary notification on item updated

Tags: wpf, dictionary

I'm using an [observabledictionary](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shimmy/2010/12/26/observabledictionarylttkey-tvaluegt-c/) , in order to get notification when any item value changed. but the problem that I can't receive any info when there's changes. here's what I use :

```
private ObservableDictionary<EnumTest, bool> _Values;

public ObservableDictionary<EnumTest, bool> Values
{
    get { return _Values; }
    set
    {
        if (_Values != value)
        {
            _Values = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Values);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you only get notified when you replace the whole `Values` dictionary

Comment: Maybe your actual use case is different, but note that whenever you create a `Dictionary<..., bool>`, think twice whether a `HashSet<...>` wouldn't do the job. In many cases, the dictionary only makes sense if you need to distinguish three states, `true`, `false`, and "not in dictionary".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper can you please explain more

Comment: @MoezRebai: I meant that if each of your `EnumTest` values is assigned a `bool` value, it is sufficient to create a `HashSet<EnumTest>` that contains exactly the values that you want to map to `true`. Rather than retrieving the `bool` value from the dictionary (and possibly checking for missing values), you can then invoke `Contains` on the hash set.

Comment: The problem that the value of the bool can change by user interaction

Comment: If you use a view model then I would recommend that you have a separate boolean property instead of a collect and trigger the `OnPropertyChanged` event when updated

Comment: Neither an enum or a bool raise any event to notify anyone that they have changed. In fact they are immutable value types so they never change. You could use an ObservableCollection<YourType> where YourType implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and raises the PropertyChanged whenever any of its properties are set. You will then be able to hook up an event handler to this event for all items that you add to the collection.

Comment: The implementation of `ObservableDictionary` you have linked to seems to raise the  `CollectionChanged` and `PropertyChanged` event when the value changes. Maybe the only thing missing is a handler for one of these events?

Answer (score 1):

Collections don't use `PropertyChanged` to notify about CollectionChanges they use [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) which fires a `CollectionChanged` Event

try listening for that instead

```
Values.CollectionChanged += (sender,args) => { /*Do something*/ };
```

personally I wouldn't touch the `ObservableDictionary` with a bargepole, instead use a `ObservableCollection<INotifyPropertyCHanged>` then you will get `CollectionChanged` when something is added to or removed from the collection and `PropertyChanged` when something inside the collection changes